# NATIVE JavaScript only - element opacity change when scrolled into viewport

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to make the elements on the page fade in on scroll. Easy enough right? Not for me.

HTML is a standard list.
CSS sets all elements to opacity 0 prior to scrolling.

I'm trying to use Native JavaScript only.

```
    // get current page body
    var actBody = document.getElementById('acts-body');

    // on scroll function
    actBody.onscroll = function(){

        // get screen height
        var screenPosition = window.innerHeight;
        // get all text elements
        var artistName = document.getElementsByClassName('artist');

        // loop through all elements
        for(var i = 0; i < artistName.length; i++){

            // get each elements position from top
            var positionFromTop = artistName[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            // if element is in viewport add class
            if(positionFromTop - screenPosition <= 0){
                artistName[i].classList.add('txt-fadeIn');
            }
            else{
                artistName[i].classList.remove('txt-fadeIn');
            }

            console.log(artistName[i]);
        }
```

Comment: The code is currently logging that the "txt-fadeIn" class is added to page elements on scroll down, and the class is removed on scroll up.

But the class doesn't seem to effect the element opacity?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i think it should solve it

```
            if(screenPosition  - positionFromTop  <= 0){
            artistName[i].classList.add('txt-fadeIn');
        }
```